# How Can I Render Data From Firestore To React Native Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to render information from my firebase to a react native component. I started by console logging what I have done, the data is being fetched completely fine:

```
displayAllPlayers(){
dbh.collection('Players').get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data().First, doc.data().Last)
    })
})}
```

I then tried to add this information to my component as follows:

```
displayAllPlayers(){
dbh.collection('Players').get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        <Player key={doc.data().First} fName={doc.data().First} lName={doc.data().Last} />
    })
})
}
render() { 
    const myPlayers = this.displayAllPlayers()
} 
return(
    {myPlayers}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

- You should return the JSX inside the `render` function.
- `displayAllPlayers` isn't returning anything.
- In this snippet

  ```
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
       <Player key={doc.data().First} fName={doc.data().First} lName={doc.data().Last} />
    })
  ```

  you're not returning anything inside the callback passed to `forEach` even if you do, it doesn't work because `forEach` doesn't return an array. You can use     [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here.
- Maintain a state in the component and update it once you get the data. Use this state for rendering the array of JSX elements.

Answer (score 1):

It's always suggested to create a different helpers file.

Create a `firebase-helpers.js` file which has an function to convert snapshot to array.

```
// FILENAME - firebase-helpers.js
export const snapshotToArray = (snapshot) => {
  let returnArr = [];

  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    let item = childSnapshot.data();

    returnArr.push(item);
  });

  return returnArr;
};
```

Now in your screen, import this file

```
import { snapshotToArray } from "../helpers/firebaseHelpers";
```

Then, convert snapshot of Players to array

```
const playersSnapshot = dbh.collection('Players').get();
const playersArray = snapshotToArray(playersSnapshot);
this.setState({ players : playersArray });
```

Now in state you have an array players. To display content of Players, you can use  in your render function as -

```
<FlatList
   data={this.state.players}
   renderItem={({ item }, index) => this.playerDisplay(item, index)}
   keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

You can then have a function to return details of players as -

```
playerDisplay = (item, index) => {
  return(
    <View>
          <Text>
                Player {index} - {item.First} {item.Last}
          </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**I hope it works fine.**